# In Solr, why is 'built' not being stemmed to 'build' but 'building' is?

Tags: lucene, solr, stemming, porter-stemmer

I'm trying to figure out two things in this posting:

1. Why is 'built' **NOT** being stemmed to 'build' even though the
   field type definition has a stemmer defined. However, 'building' is
   being stemmed to 'build'
2. How to use Luke to examine the index to see which words got stemmed
   and to what. I wasn't able to see 'building' being stemmed 'build'
   in Luke. I know Lucene is stemming it because I am able to
   successfully retrieve the row with 'building' by searching for
   'build'.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285916/how-to-configure-stemming-in-solr/5285978#5285978) was pretty helpful but didn't answer my questions.

For reference, here is the schema.xml portions.

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and the field definition is

```
<field name="features" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

The data set consists of multiple documents, 1 document has 'building' in the features field, 1 documents has 'built' in the same field, and 1 document has 'Built-in' in the features field:

file : hd.xml:

```
<field name="features">building NoiseGuard, SilentSeek technology, Fluid Dynamic Bearing (FDB) motor</field>
```

file ipod_video.xml:

```
<field name="features">Notes, Calendar, Phone book, Hold button, Date display, Photo wallet, Built-in games, JPEG photo playback, Upgradeable firmware, USB 2.0 compatibility, Playback speed control, Rechargeable capability, Battery level indication</field>
```

file sd500.xml:

```
 <field name="features">built in flash, red-eye reduction</field>
```

Using Lukeall-3.3.0, This is the result I get from searching for 'features:build'. Notice that I get back 1 (instead of the expected 3 documents)
[image]
Even within that one document, I don't see the stemming, ie, I only see the original word, 'building' as shown:
[image]

and, again in Luke, searching for 'features:built', returns two documents:
[image]

Selecting one of them, shows the original 'built' but not 'build'.
[image]

Comment: Just to comment for anyone who finds this through Google later - what you're asking for is usually called lemmatisation, not stemming (as stemming usually just chops of the ends of words, and does not derive any context or meaning from the word itself, neither does it use a dictionary to look up other forms of the same word).

Answer (score 2):

For exceptional cases like this, you can tune the stemming algorithm with [StemmerOverrideFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Customizing_Stemming)

Comment: Thank you Robert. I wouldn't have thought that built is exceptional. I am under the impression that *all* English language words can be stemmed to their roots. Built/build, choose/chose, lead/led, ... are all examples that I would presume the PorterFilter would be able to handle. Otherwise, if it doesn't, how would I know which ones it doesn't unless I try the entire dictionary or wait for a user to complain.